# Change pyspark dataframe column after fixed offset from a given line

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Short Version**

The task is to "go through" a pyspark dataframe, ordered by time. Whenever a keyword appears, we need to add another keyword in the same column a fixed time later.

**Example**

Consider the following data frame:

```py
columns = ["time","ID","marker"]
data = [
    (0.0, "ID1", None), 
    (0.1, "ID1", "Start"), 
    (0.2, "ID1", None), 
    (0.3, "ID1", None), 
    (0.4, "ID1", None), 
    (0.5, "ID1", None), 
    
    (0.0, "ID2", "Boot"), 
    (0.5, "ID2", None), 
    (1.0, "ID2", None), 
    (1.5, "ID2", "Start"), 
    (2.0, "ID2", None), 
    (2.5, "ID2", None), 
    ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)
df.show()

+----+---+------+
|time| ID|marker|
+----+---+------+
| 0.0|ID1|  null|
| 0.1|ID1| Start|
| 0.2|ID1|  null|
| 0.3|ID1|  null|
| 0.4|ID1|  null|
| 0.5|ID1|  null|
| 0.0|ID2|  Boot|
| 0.5|ID2|  null|
| 1.0|ID2|  null|
| 1.5|ID2| Start|
| 2.0|ID2|  null|
| 2.5|ID2|  null|
+----+---+------+
```

My task is to add the string `End` to the `marker` column, at the nearest time after 0.15s have passed since each occurence of the `Start` string. For clarification, my desired result is:

```
+----+---+------+
|time| ID|marker|
+----+---+------+
| 0.0|ID1|  null|
| 0.1|ID1| Start| <- Start the clock
| 0.2|ID1|  null| <- 0.15s have not elapsed yet
| 0.3|ID1|   End| <- 0.15s have elapsed! Write "End"
| 0.4|ID1|  null|
| 0.5|ID1|  null|
| 0.0|ID2|  Boot|
| 0.5|ID2|  null|
| 1.0|ID2|  null|
| 1.5|ID2| Start| <- Start the clock
| 2.0|ID2|   End| <- 0.15s have elapsed! Write "End"
| 2.5|ID2|  Null|
+----+---+------+
```

**Research so far**

The window function combined with lag seemed most promising, but it allows only lags of rows, not seconds. I tried faking this behavior with a lag, calculating `lines_per_second` first:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy(F.col("ID")).orderBy("time").rangeBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)
lines_per_second = (F.lit(-1) + F.count("time").over(w)) / (F.max("time").over(w) - F.min("time").over(w))

+----+---+------+----------------+
|time| ID|marker|lines_per_second|
+----+---+------+----------------+
| 0.0|ID1|  null|            10.0|
| 0.1|ID1| Start|            10.0|
| 0.2|ID1|  null|            10.0|
| 0.3|ID1|  null|            10.0|
| 0.4|ID1|  null|            10.0|
| 0.5|ID1|  null|            10.0|
| 0.0|ID2|  Boot|             2.0|
| 0.5|ID2|  null|             2.0|
| 1.0|ID2|  null|             2.0|
| 1.5|ID2| Start|             2.0|
| 2.0|ID2|  null|             2.0|
| 2.5|ID2|  null|             2.0|
+----+---+------+----------------+
```

But I'm stuck all the same. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See inline comments for explanations:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'start',    # Find the start time for each ID
    F.max(
        F.when(F.col('marker') == 'Start', F.col('time'))
    ).over(Window.partitionBy('ID'))
).withColumn(
    'end',     # Add 0.15s elapsed time
    F.col('start') + 0.15
).withColumn(
    'marker2',     # Find the row which is the earliest after 0.15s has elapsed
    F.row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy('ID')
              .orderBy(F.when(F.col('end') < F.col('time'), F.col('time')).asc_nulls_last())
    ) == 1
).withColumn(
    'marker',    # update marker
    F.coalesce(
        'marker', 
        F.when(F.col('marker2'), F.lit('End'))
    )
).select(
    df.columns    # remove temporary columns
).orderBy('ID', 'time')

df2.show()
+----+---+------+
|time| ID|marker|
+----+---+------+
| 0.0|ID1|  null|
| 0.1|ID1| Start|
| 0.2|ID1|  null|
| 0.3|ID1|   End|
| 0.4|ID1|  null|
| 0.5|ID1|  null|
| 0.0|ID2|  Boot|
| 0.5|ID2|  null|
| 1.0|ID2|  null|
| 1.5|ID2| Start|
| 2.0|ID2|   End|
| 2.5|ID2|  null|
+----+---+------+
```